# Jersey/web.xml/Servlet Routing Issue

Tags: java, rest, web-applications, jersey, jax-rs

So this will be mostly code to illustrate the issue, but issue as follows:

pointing my browser to localhost:8080/licsrv/items return 404.

revelant web.xml

```
<!-- Java Remoting Servlet -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>licenseGenService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.context.support.HttpRequestHandlerServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>licenseGenService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/remoting/licensing</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Restful API Servlet-->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>licensingRestService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>
                    com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages
            </param-name>
            <param-value>
                mypackage.rest
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>licensingRestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/orders</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>licensingRestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/items</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>licensingRestService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/customers</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

ItemsResourceImpl.java

```
@Path("/items")
public class ItemsResourceImpl implements ItemsResource 
{

@GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String testItems()
    {
        return "<html><body><h1>Items Resource Tester</h1><p>Items Resource is available.</p></body></html>";
    }

.....
}
```

And then I have the bean in my applicationContext.xml

Now ItemsResource (an interface) also has annotations and methods defined, could this be the issue? My impression was that Jax-RS annotations are not inherited. Is it the fact that I have two servlets and am missing something? I have a pure REST service with just one servlet and same configuration doing the same thing. Depending on how I change the configuration I get 405 Method Not Allowed out of it as well. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing `http://localhost:8080/licsrv/items/items`. The `@Path` annotation defines the path relative to the application's root (which are defined by the servlet mapping in web.xml).

Answer (score 0):

The servlet mapping is suspicious for me. I'm not familiar with spring, but if servlet mapping is something like this:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>licensingRestService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/orders/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The url should like: `localhost:8080/licsrv/orders/items`, with the same `ItemsResourceImpl` implementation.

Comment: There are three distinct rest classes, the ItemsResourceImpl, CustomersResourceImpl, and OrdersResourceImpl which should respond on /orders /customers and /items respectively.

Comment: Question and Answer here differ in `/*`. I think they are missing in the OPs web.xml.